# SQL Server - Group and sum but ignore empty or null values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL server and want to run a group by query on the ColB and ColC. The table looks like this

```
ColA   | ColB    | ColC
----------------------------
8      | 11      | 12
2      | 22      | 22
3      |         |  
6      |         |  
2      | 11      | 12
4      |         | 
5      |         |
```

But my query also groups the null and empty and then provides the sum for the empty values.

```
Select Sum(ColA), ColB, ColC from testTable group by ColB, ColC
```

In my case, the empty values must be ignored and not considered for the grouping. So the expected result is

```
ColA   | ColB    | ColC
----------------------------
10     | 11      | 12
2      | 22      | 22
3      |         |  
6      |         |  
4      |         | 
5      |         |
```

But the actual result for the query is

```
ColA   | ColB    | ColC
----------------------------
10     | 11      | 12
2      | 22      | 22
18     |         |
```

How can the grouping of empty values be ignored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
Select Sum(ColA), ColB, ColC
from testTable
group by ColB, ColC,
         (case when colB is null and colC is null then colA end);
```

Or use `union all`:

```
select sum(cola), colb, colc
from testTable
where colb is not null or colc is not null
group by colb, colc
union all
select cola, colb, colc
from testTable
where colb is null and colc is null;
```

This is more accurate if `cola` can have duplicate values with `null`s in the other column.

Answer (score 1):

One more simple solution:

```
Select Sum(ColA), COALESCE(ColB, 0 ) AS ColB, COALESCE(ColC, 0) AS ColC
from testTable
group by ColB, COALESCE(ColB, 0), COALESCE(ColC, 0);
```

**Note:**
You have to change coalesce second para '0' to non-existing value.

Answer (score 0):

With `SUM()` window function:

```
select distinct
  case 
    when ColB is null and ColC is null then ColA 
    else sum(ColA) over (partition by ColB, ColC) 
  end ColA, 
  ColB, ColC
from testTable
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4b21dd634534aadc0a3cab27055291f5).
Results:

```
> ColA | ColB | ColC
> ---: | ---: | ---:
>    2 |   22 |   22
>    3 |      |     
>    4 |      |     
>    5 |      |     
>    6 |      |     
>   10 |   11 |   12
```